# The effect scroll horizontal as Yahoo Weather iOS App

Tags: ios

Someone can help me about the effect scrollview swipe as Yahoo Weather iOS App?
Thanks!

```
self.backgroundView = [[DKLiveBlurView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];        
    NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:randomId] ofType:@"png"];        
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
    self.backgroundView.originalImage = image;
    self.backgroundView.scrollView = self.tableView;
    self.backgroundView.isGlassEffectOn = YES;
    self.tableView.backgroundView = self.backgroundView;
```

Comment: Do you mean using paging?

Comment: yes,i think it need 2 layer for transition effect,of course,we should use Paging and UIScrollView.But at the time, i had just confusing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Weather App is using [`UIPageController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html) and the transition effect comes automatically with it. You can find many tutorials about how it works (Take a look to this [one](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/) for example).

In your app's view controller header file, add a property for the `UIPageViewController`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourAppViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageController;

@end
```

In your app's view controller .m file, implement these methods:

- To increase/decrease the screen index and return the view controller to display):

  ```
  - (UIViewController *) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
  {
      NSUInteger index = [(YourAppViewController *)viewController index];
      if (index == 0) {
          return nil;
      }

      index--;

      return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
  }

  - (UIViewController *) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
  viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
  {
      NSUInteger index = [(YourAppViewController *)viewController index];
      index++;

      if (index == 5) {
          return nil;
      }

      return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
  }
  ```
- Finally, to set the number of dots in the page indicator and which dot must be
  selected at the beginning.

  ```
  - (NSInteger) presentationCountForPageViewController:
    (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
  {
      // The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
      return 5;
  }

  - (NSInteger) presentationIndexForPageViewController:
  (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
  {
      // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it using UIScrollView with paging. By Setting appropriate contentOffset on didScroll you can achieve the parallax effect like in Yahoo weather. There's a great video on WWDC 2013 about nested scroll views which can be referred to.

I have also created a sample project using scrollView which implements that parallax effect- https://github.com/vin25/SideScrollParallaxEffect-iOS

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the parallax effect of Yahoo Weather using a plain UIPageViewController subclass, and autolayout constraints for the parallax effect of the background images.
(I didn't want to recreate a whole scrollView with pages, as I was convinced the UIPageViewController already handles a lot of stuff for free).

Here it is : 
https://github.com/frederic-adda/TestParallax/tree/master